# What is SSH - the protocol and what is ssh - the utility?

Tags: ssh, solaris, su, sftp

What is SSH - the protocol?
What is `ssh` - the unix utility and how does it work?

How is SSH protocol related to SFTP?

What is `sshd`?

Does the command `su` use `ssh` or `sshd`?

Comment: I work on Solaris and though i have been using the commands ssh, sftp and su for quite sometime now, i have never completely understood how they work. Please explain and point me towards some good resources where i can learn more.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The SSH protocol is defined by what the `ssh` and `sshd` programs accept.  (There is a standard defined for it, but it's an after-the-fact thing and is mostly ignored when one of the implementations adds new features.)  Since there are multiple implementations of those (OpenSSH, F-Secure, PuTTY, etc.) occasionally you'll find that one of them doesn't support the same protocol as the others.  Basically, it defines authentication negotiation and creation of a multiplexed data stream.  This stream can carry one or more (with OpenSSH and `ControlMaster`) terminal sessions and zero or more tunnels (forwarding socket connections from either local or remote to the other side; X11 forwarding is a special case of remote forwarding).  It also defines "subsystems" that can be used over the stream; terminal sessions are the basic subsystem but others can be defined.  `sftp` is one of these.

`ssh` the utility uses the SSH protocol to talk to `sshd` on another machine.  How it works depends on what version it is (see above), but the gist of it is that it attempts to figure out which version of the SSH protocol to use, then it and `sshd` negotiate supported authentication methods, then it tries to authenticate you using one of those methods (asking for remote user password/private key paasword/S-Key phrase as necessary), and on successful authentication sets up a multiplexed stream with the `sshd`.

`sshd`, as said above, implements the server side of the SSH protocol.

`sftp` is a (at present, the only standard) subsystem defined in most `sshd` implementations.  When the SFTP subsystem is requested, `sshd` connects `sftp-server` to the subsystem session; the `sftp` program then talks to it, similarly to `ftp` but with file transfers multiplexed on the stream instead of using separate connections as with `ftp`.

`su` has nothing to do with `ssh`, `sshd`, or `sftp`, except insofar as there may be PAM modules to arrange for the multiplexed stream to be available within the shell or program run by it.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it again. Nicely comprehensive answer - upvoted.

Answer (score 9):

SSH (stands for "Secure SHell") is a network protocol which described in [RFC4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251). `ssh` utility is SSH client that connects to SSH daemon and presents "Secure SHell" to user. SFTP is FTP-like protocol which works over SSH connection.

`su` command does not use `ssh` or `sshd` in any way, it just allows you to run processes with different privileges.

Answer (score 6):

[**SSH**](http://www.snailbook.com/protocols.html) is a protocol for secure communication over an insecure network. It allows for end to end encryption of all communication such that it cannot (feasibly) be intercepted and decrytped.

**[ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)** the utility is an implementation of the protocol. **[SFTP](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp)** is a subsystem of ssh that uses the protocol for secure password and file transfer.

**[su](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)** does not use the ssh protocol.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [OpenSSH project](http://www.openssh.com/). It has all the info you're looking for.

Briefly, the **SSH protocol** permits the *secure* (encrypted) connection between two hosts.
The `ssh` utility is a client program to log into a remote system using the SSH protocol, and it has a lot of other uses, too, like [reverse] tunneling/port forwarding/...

`sshd` it's the *server* software. It provides a *daemon* which responds to incoming SSH requests.

`su` has nothing to do with ssh. It's used to change the active user (the most frequent use it's to become `root`).