# How to connect to another machine over SSH?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible, by simply issuing:

```
ssh user@ip_number:port
```

and providing a password?

Or does something have to be installed, or not blocked?

I am referring to two machines over the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SSH daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) has to be listening on the machine you are attempting to connect to (and be [configured to accept the connection](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys)).

The machine you are attempting to connect to will also need to have an open port if it is running [a firewall](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firewalls); the default for SSH being 22.

If it is sitting behind a router, you will need to have [a port forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) as well.

The Arch Wiki has a good guide on [setting up SSH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ssh).

If you are intending to set up an SSH daemon, you are **strongly advised** to use [public keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ssh_keys) rather than passwords to authenticate, and to disable password authentication with the following lines in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

---

Also see these other questions:

- [Why is root login over SSH so bad that everyone advises to disable it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it)
- [Why change the default SSH port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/why-change-default-ssh-port)
- [What is SSH the protocol and `ssh` the utility?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/what-is-ssh-the-protocol-and-what-is-ssh-the-utility)
- [What's the purpose of ssh-agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72552/whats-the-purpose-of-ssh-agent)
- [Advice for managing SSH keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94568/advice-for-managing-ssh-keys)